# Prevent FIM from looping back to first image

Tags: shell-script, image-viewer

I was looking to use FIM (fbi improved) to triage images, and would like it to not loop round, so its obvious when the list is complete. Prefereably it'd just close, but I'd be happy with any solution.

I was wondering if this is possible?

Would be happy to use a differrent program that has similar functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `~/.fimrc` you can put:

```
alias 'next_noloop' 'if(_fileindex<_filelistlen)next;';                                                                       
alias 'prev_noloop' 'if(_fileindex>1)prev;';
bind 'n' 'next_noloop';
bind 'p' 'prev_noloop';
```

The variables mentioned above are documented in `man fimrc` (https://www.nongnu.org/fbi-improved/#man_fimrc).

p.s.: finally FIM-0.6, or first stable release since years, is out ;-) https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/fbi-improved-devel/2023-04/msg00000.html

Comment: Thank you for the help (and leading me onto the power of `.fimrc`). Changing the top line to `alias 'next_noloop' 'if(_fileindex<_filelistlen){next;}else{quit;}';` will cause `fim` to quit at the end. Very exciting about the latest release!